# Java: Temperature Converter Not Working

Tags: java

When the values 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 and 60 are entered they do not covert from Celsius to Fahrenheit correctly. They produce the result: 42.0 52.0 62.0 72.0 82.0 92.0

10 Degrees Celsius should be 50 rather than 40 Fahrenheit for example.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double temperatureArray [] = new double [6];
        double fahrenheitArray [] = new double [6];

        for (int i=0; i<temperatureArray.length; i++) {
            temperatureArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please Enter The Temperature"));
            fahrenheitArray [i] = temperatureArray[i];
        }

        temperatureConvert(fahrenheitArray);

        for (int i=0; i<fahrenheitArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(fahrenheitArray [i] +" ");
        }

    }

    public static void temperatureConvert(double fahrenheitArray[]) {
        for (int i=0; i<fahrenheitArray.length; i++) {
            fahrenheitArray[i] = (9/5) * fahrenheitArray[i] + 32;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: change ``(9/5)`` to ``(9./5.)``

Comment: Jist an idea, maybe it takes 9 and 5 as ints, and therefore that division is made as int. Try changing (9/5) to (9.0/5)

Comment: Right you are: 9 and 5 are `int`s alright. `(9/5)` equals 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9/5 gives an integer which would be 1. You should do 9/5.0 to get the correct values.